# Job starts before previous job finishes

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Pipelines stage with two jobs (`job: Publish` and `deployment: Deploy`).

Sometimes the job `deployment: Deploy` starts running before `job: Publish` finishes.

I get an error and then I need to wait to `job: Publish` finishes and rerun `deployment: Deploy`.

When I rerun `deployment: Deploy` everything goes well ...

**Question**
Why does `deployment: Deploy` starts before `job: Publish` finishes?

Here is the YML code for that stage:

```
- stage: Production
  dependsOn: Staging
  jobs:
  - job: Publish
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'
    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: Setup
      inputs:
        packageType: sdk
        version: 3.0.x
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Publish
      inputs:
        command: publish
        publishWebProjects: false
        projects: 'src/**/*.csproj'
        arguments: '--configuration production --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        zipAfterPublish: true
    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
      displayName: Export
      inputs:
        artifactName: Production
        targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  - deployment: Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: Ubuntu-16.04
    environment: production
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@1
            displayName: Import
            inputs:
              artifactName: Production
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@3
            displayName: Api
            inputs:
              package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Api.zip'
              removeAdditionalFilesFlag: true
              azureSubscription: '$(azure.subscription)'
              appType: 'Web App on Linux'
              webAppName: 'app-api'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because when the syntax you are using does not include job dependency, at this time, it is the one which would [build in parallel (no dependencies)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#dependencies).

If you do not specified dependency and the actual organization situation allows [parallelism](http://Parallel%20jobs), these jobs will run in parallel.

**BUT**, if org itself does not meet the parallel conditions, also the user does not specify the job order (dependency). Now the server will run the job **randomly**. Because the jobs which without dependency relationship are two separate jobs for the server.

**Note:** This only occur with YAML schema, Classic editor has default execution order.

---

To solve the trouble you were, just add `dependsOn: Publish` in your `deployment: Deploy` job:

```
  - deployment: Deploy
    dependsOn: Publish
    pool:
      vmImage: Ubuntu-16.04
    environment: production
```

Now, the `deployment: Deploy` will only run after the `job: Publish` finished.